# Create simple smooth page scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have been trying to make a simple JS page scroller.
I have tried using scrollTo which jumps and setting the behaviour to smooth seems way to fast.
My solution was to use requestAnimationFrame in conjunction with scrollBy.

I am pretty happy with this, simple and effective, I am not a pro!

My question to throw out there: would anybody have any simple(ish) suggestions on how to add an ease-in-out effect to the animation?

```js
//Set inital position
let scrollPosition = (window.scrollY);
//element to scroll into view
let elOffset = document.getElementById('test-div').offsetTop;

//Update scroll position on scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollPosition = Math.round(this.scrollY);
})

//Loop/stop smooth ani of js scrollby
rockAndScroll = () => {
  window.scrollBy(0, 7);
  if (scrollPosition <= elOffset) {
    requestAnimationFrame(rockAndScroll);
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(rockAndScroll);
  }
}

//Inital smooth ani of js scrollby
scrollScreen = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(rockAndScroll)
};

//Start on timer
setTimeout(scrollScreen, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #777;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
}

p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.sect {
  border: solid 0px #fff;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sect-1 {
  background: #666;
}

.sect-2 {
  background: #333;
}

.sect-3 {
  background: #666;
}

.sect-4 {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section class="sect sect-1">
    <p>Section 1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="sect sect-2">
    <p>Section 2</p>
  </section>
  <section id="test-div" class="sect sect-3">
    <p>Section 3</p>
  </section>
  <section class="sect sect-4">
    <p>Section 4</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This article might help you: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-scrolling-vanilla-javascript--cms-35165

Answer (score 2):

Dead simple (if you care about IE then [that might not be the case](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior)):

```css
html { /* Or another overflowed element of your choice */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This solution does not guarantee an ease-in-out effect but it's probably the easiest one can come up with.

Try it:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 50px 50px / 50px 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}

#menu a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000;
}

.sect {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sect:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#sect-1">1</a>
  <a href="#sect-2">2</a>
  <a href="#sect-3">3</a>
  <a href="#sect-4">4</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <section class="sect" id="sect-1">
    <p>Section 1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="sect" id="sect-2">
    <p>Section 2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="sect" id="sect-3">
    <p>Section 3</p>
  </section>
  <section class="sect" id="sect-4">
    <p>Section 4</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this scroll-behaviour:smooth is just as bad as JS scrollTo. 
The scrolling is way to fast and pretty unpleasant on the eye.